# Reference a constructor argument from a trait

Tags: scala, constructor, scala-2.9, traits

In Scala, is it possible for a trait to reference a named constructor argument of the class it is mixed into? The code below doesn't compile because ModuleDao's constructor argument is not a val as defined in the trait. If I add `val` before the constructor argument to make it public, it matches up with the one in the trait and it compiles, but I'd prefer not to set it as a `val`.

```
trait Daoisms {
  val sessionFactory:SessionFactory
  protected def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession
}

class ModuleDao(sessionFactory:SessionFactory) extends Daoisms {
  def save(module:Module) = session.saveOrUpdate(module)
}

/* Compiler error:
class ModuleDao needs to be abstract, since value sessionFactory in trait Daoisms of type org.hibernate.SessionFactory is not defined */

// This works though
// class ModuleDao(val sessionFactory:SessionFactory) extends Daoisms { ... }
```

Comment: Why not set it as a `val`? You are already doing so on `Daoism`, so why not do so on `ModuleDao`? The problem is that, the way you are declaring, `sessionFactory` is effectively private -- no one else can see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your only concern with making it a val is visibility, you can just make the val protected like so:

```
scala> trait D { protected val d:Int
     | def dd = d
     | }
defined trait D

scala> class C(protected val d:Int) extends D
defined class C

scala> new C(1)
res0: C = C@ba2e48

scala> res0.d
<console>:11: error: value d in class C cannot be accessed in C
 Access to protected value d not permitted because
 enclosing class object $iw in object $iw is not a subclass of 
 class C in object $iw where target is defined
              res0.d
                   ^

scala> res0.dd
res2: Int = 1
```

Comment: Thanks - in the interest of brevity I may go with just `val` and accept that it's publicly visible. It's only used internally so public isn't too public in this case.